# Data insertion error: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm using Django-nonrel on Google App Engine. I'm trying to add a row to the database but I get this error when trying to use save():

> invalid literal for int() with base 10

Here's my code:

views.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from forms import SayForm
from models import Saying, Category
import datetime

def say_something(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SayForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        content = cd['content']
        category_temp = "Uncategorized"
        category = Category.objects.get(name = category_temp)
        added_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        added_user = request.user
        saying = Saying(content, category, added_date, added_user)
        saying.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contribute/success')
else:
    form = SayForm()
return render_to_response('say_form.html', {'form' : form})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Saying(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length = 160)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    added_date = models.DateField()
    added_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class SayForm(forms.Form):
    content = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)

    def clean_message(self):
        content = self.cleaned_data['content']
        num_characters = len(content)
        if num_characters > 160:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please limit your saying to 160 characters only.")
        num_words = len(content.split())
        if num_words < 4:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This doesn't make sense. Say something longer.")
        return content
```

Edit: here's the backtrace

> Traceback: File
>   "/home/eeyorexd/workspace/Python/appengine/something-to-say/somethingtosay/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     107.                         response = callback(request,
>   *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/eeyorexd/workspace/Python/appengine/something-to-say/somethingtosay/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py"
>   in _wrapped_view
>     25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/eeyorexd/workspace/Python/appengine/something-to-say/somethingtosay/core/views.py"
>   in say_something
>     36.             saying.save()
>
> File
>   "/home/eeyorexd/workspace/Python/appengine/something-to-say/somethingtosay/django/db/models/base.py"
>   in save
>     452.         self.save_base(using=using,
>   force_insert=force_insert,
>   force_update=force_update)
>
> File
>   "/home/eeyorexd/workspace/Python/appengine/something-to-say/somethingtosay/django/db/models/base.py"
>   in save_base
>     550.                         for f in meta.local_fields]
>
> File
>   "/home/eeyorexd/workspace/Python/appengine/something-to-say/somethingtosay/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py"
>   in inner
>     28.             return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/eeyorexd/workspace/Python/appengine/something-to-say/somethingtosay/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py"
>   in inner
>     28.             return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/eeyorexd/workspace/Python/appengine/something-to-say/somethingtosay/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py"
>   in get_db_prep_save
>     280.         return self.get_db_prep_value(value,
>   connection=connection, prepared=False)
>
> File
>   "/home/eeyorexd/workspace/Python/appengine/something-to-say/somethingtosay/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py"
>   in inner
>     53.             return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/eeyorexd/workspace/Python/appengine/something-to-say/somethingtosay/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py"
>   in get_db_prep_value
>     492.         return connection.ops.value_to_db_auto(value)
>
> File
>   "/home/eeyorexd/workspace/Python/appengine/something-to-say/somethingtosay/djangotoolbox/db/base.py"
>   in value_to_db_auto
>     68.         return super(NonrelDatabaseOperations,
>   self).value_to_db_auto(value)
>
> File
>   "/home/eeyorexd/workspace/Python/appengine/something-to-say/somethingtosay/django/db/backends/**init**.py"
>   in value_to_db_auto
>     485.         return int(value)
>
> Exception Type: ValueError at
>   /contribute/ Exception Value: invalid
>   literal for int() with base 10: 'test'

My gut feeling tells me that the problem lies somewhere around how I save the object to the database. Maybe the foreign key part? I can't pinpoint the problem since I just started learning Django recently. Does this problem have anything to do with Django-nonrel using GAE's backend? Can anyone tell me where I went wrong here?

Comment: The backtrace which it should have given you would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm still a noob at this so it's kind of hard to figure this out on my own, even with the backtrace present. I'll add it here and hope someone can tell me where I went wrong.

Comment: There is enough information to get what's needed from the traceback if that had been needed (not sure if the answerers used it), but it's helpful formatted as code (010101 button) rather than as blockquote - it preserves whitespace and formats it more nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
saying = Saying(content, category, added_date, added_user)
```

You've forgotten that Django adds an automatic `id` field to the model definition. If you did this in the shell, then printed `saying.__dict__`, you would see that the content has been assigned to `id`, the category to `content`, and so on.

Instead, always use keyword arguments when instantiating a model:

```
saying = Saying(content=content, 
                category=category, 
                added_date=added_date, 
                added_user=added_user)
```

Comment: OMG, I completely forgot about the automatic id field. No wonder I keep getting errors. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Creating an instance like this will set the primary key of your model to `content`:

```
saying = Saying(content, category, added_date, added_user)
```

Which won't work, because your model has a numeric primary key, as do all models by default unless you explicitly tell it to use some other field for the primary key. When Django tries to call `int()` on the value to cast it to integer, it crashes with a type error.

You should instead use keyword arguments, like this:

```
saying = Saying(content = content, ... = ...)
```

The idiomatic way to do this, as you want to save the object anyway:

```
saying = Saying.objects.create(content = content, ... = ..)
```